# For CDI injection, do I need META-INF/beans.xml in the producer archive AND the injectee archive?

Tags: cdi, jsr299

Perhaps it's just too many hours of combing through the [CDI 1.0 specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/), but I couldn't find a detailed description of exactly where a `META-INF/beans.xml` was required.

(The [section on bean discovery](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/packagingdeployment.html#beandiscovery) makes a few tantalizing statements that imply certain things, but I'm not sure if it's prescriptive.)

I understand that loosely speaking any bean archive needs one.

But consider a case with the following jars in a compliant CDI 1.0 environment:

- An *interface jar* containing interfaces only
- An *implementation jar* containing CDI beans that implement those interfaces and that feature `@Inject` injection points, but no producer methods
- A *producer jar* containing (for simplicity) a single Java object with a single method that has been annotated with `@Produces`.

It seems logical that both the *producer jar* and the *implementation jar* would need to be bean archives, and so hence would each need `META-INF/beans.xml` resources contained within them.

But for completeness, is this in fact the case?  Since the *implementation jar* only uses an `@Inject` point and no CDI annotations, would it be scanned by other means?  Another way to look at it: in this example, the *implementation jar* is used *only* as the *target* for injections, not the *source* of injectables.  So I could see some sort of logic that would say: look, only jars that produce beans that *can be injected* need to be declared as bean archives.  (I'm not saying that's true; just that I could see that argument being made.)

Finally, there's the whole issue of the *interface jar*.  By definition it doesn't contain beans, but I've seen cases long ago with GlassFish where even the *interface jar* had to have a `META-INF/beans.xml` file in it.  That seems wrong to me, but I found to my surprise that I couldn't really find a section in the specification to confirm or deny this.

So: `beans.xml` everywhere?  Only in injectable-producing jars?  Only in injection-target jars?  Or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a.) You need the beans.xml marker file in both producer and impl jar

b.) You don't need the beans.xml marker file on pure interface jars. If GlassFish fails, then this is a gf bug. It doesn't do any harm though.